# Date Picker issue in tabbed parent child activity

Tags: android

I am using Date Picker in Child Activity of tabbed parent. It Works fine for the first time when I click on set date but when return from child to parent and then again go to child from tabbed parent and click on set date app crashes  with

```
 android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token  
 android.app.LocalActivityManager$LocalActivity
```

Any help will be welcomed if need code for understanding scenario I will post here.